# safari/chrome onsubmit="location.reload(true)" not working

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, safari, onsubmit

A form on my website is not functioning correctly in Safari/Chrome.  When a user submits the form, it opens up a new tab, but I want the original page (page with the form on it) to reload.    It works in IE, Opera, and Firefox.

The Code:

```
<form action="/search.php" method="post" onsubmit="location.reload(true)" target="_blank" name="myform">
```

I tried other javascript functions like:

- window.location.reload();
- document.location.reload();
- window.location.replace('http://www.websiteurl.com');
- window.location.href='http://www.websiteurl.com';
- And other variations of these.

I thought maybe it was the onsubmit="" not working, but when I tried onsubmit="alert('test')" that worked fine in both Safari/Chrome.

Also, on the search.php page that the form posts to, if a user goes directly to the page using the url, and not submitting the form, I have it set that the body tag will load as:

```
<body onload="window.location.replace("http://www.websiteurl.com")>
```

which works on all browsers includeing Safari/Chrome.

What is going on here?!?!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work regularly, but a `setTimeout` hack works: http://jsfiddle.net/xzanQ/.

Comment: Do you want the new tab to open as well?

Comment: I've had a similar problem with reloading not working in all bowsers (though not in the context of form reloading) and ended up with: window.location=window.location;

Comment: I do want to open a new tab aswell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it was the solution for you:

Using `setTimeout` sometimes works as a hacky solution by postponing execution for a very short time: http://jsfiddle.net/xzanQ/.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit` gets executed before a form is posted. If a page is already being unloaded, the form may not be submitted anymore.

Try something like:

```
var myForm=document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm.addEventListener('submit',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  this.submit();//Submit the form BEFORE reloading
  location.reload(true);      
},false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just faced a similar problemnd after debugging for hours I found out that a ; was missing in my onsubmit statement..

Changing:

onsubmit="location.reload(true)"

To:

onsubmit="location.reload(true);"

Fixed my safari on mac problem..