# How to make jQuery work with mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, mobile

So my page works on IE, Chrome and Firefox, and works on my friends galaxy phone. It is simply:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateCart(itemid,todo)  
    {

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.get("http://www.example.com/updatecart.php?itemnumber=" + itemid + "&todo=" +     todo, function(){location.reload(true)});
    return false;
    }
</script>
```

and then the link which a user should click to do the action:

```
<a name='removefromcart' id='removefromcart' href='#' onClick='javascript:UpdateCart("60813","remove");return false;'>Remove Item</a>
```

When I use my personal cell phone(not my friend's), the page renders all fine. The page even has an onClick event to open a new window, and that onclick even works. But the onClick events with jQuery functions don't work, they just don't do anything. I have tried the code on text, as well as a button, to no avail.

I was told to use jQuery mobile, but I tried researching it and couldn't find out how to use it or what code to put where. I AM A NUBLETT! Sorry!

EDIT: Just tried my brothers iPhone 5, and it did NOT work either. So mobile issue is def there I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what cell you're using, could it be that it doesn't have appropriate support for Ajax? Check out: http://quirksmode.org/m/table.html

Comment: My cell phone is Kyocera Event(cheap $65 smartphone with android. bought new, this year) Has an app called Browser, but also has Google Chrome. And I have tried both of its browsers!

Comment: I should also mention, my site does NOT have a mobile version, but I've never had a problem using my phone on my site anyway.

Comment: It might be an issue with location.reload; another post at stackoverflow had people run into an issue with it and they replaced location.reload with window.location=window.location. You can see the other posting at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573333/safari-chrome-onsubmit-location-reloadtrue-not-working

Comment: Add a fail handler to see if the request is failing. Tack on the following to the end of your $.get to determine if the request failed.
`.fail(function() { alert("error"); });`

Comment: If the request isn't failing, change location.reload(true) to document.location.reload(true) and see if that works.

Comment: tried that too, not working. also the error does not come up. no alerts trigger. it seems like it just totally ignores the function. Let me try to do a document.write in the function as the first line. see if that even runs to begin with.

Comment: okay, so I took out the ajax/get section of the function, and did just a document.write("asdf"); and it worked. So the mobile browser is def recognizing the onclick, but it is having problems with ajax/get somehow.

Comment: @Dave Fes
Glad you got it sorted out. It might be related to "Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol." Even though you were going to the same domain via the same protocol/port, having a leading http:// blocked the Ajax call. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue. I assume the browser is set up this way for SECURITY issues!

Okay, so I took out the absolute path on the ajax function. Instead of doing 
     http://www.example.com/filename.php/asdfasdf

I just did 
    filename.php/blahblah?id=.....

You get the idea! I assume they don't want external requests being made, so when http is detected, it's a no go