# Safari 7.0.1 and onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, safari, onsubmit

Due to Safari (7.0.1 / Mac OS), I'm struggling with a simple Javascript problem. I submit a form, and I want to display an icon during the page loading.

From what I can see, it's not related to the javascript itself, but more to the onsubmit behavior (if I move it outside the function, it does the expected job when loading the page instead of at "submit" time).

This is my code (working perfectly on Chrome and Firefox). Any idea?

```
<html>
<body>    
  <img id="loadingImage" src="assets/images/loadingIcon.png" style="display:none;"/>
  <form method="POST" action="js.php" onsubmit="loadLoader()">
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>   
  </form>

<script  type="text/javascript">
function loadLoader(){
    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display = 'block';
    return true;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you remove the `onsubmit` event and instead call loadLoader() in an `onclick` event on the input. maybe `onclick` is more supported by all browsers, and logically results in the form being submitted?

Comment: hello Félix, I have the exact same behavior with the onclick of the input of type "submit".

Comment: it's funny. according to this page http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/ the submit event should be fully supported by safari.

Comment: Indeed. I've just seen that on my iPad Air, the behavior is the one expected. It looks like a bug on Safari Mac 7.0.1...

Comment: Still not working in Safari 7.0.5

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573333/safari-chrome-onsubmit-location-reloadtrue-not-working It may help you

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't comment your post due my reputation. As you JS code is non blocking I tried to move it to the head and added `javascript` before the function call. I tested it in Safari 7.0.1 and it worked.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadLoader() {
            alert('loadLoader called');
            document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display = 'block';
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="loadingImage" src="assets/images/loadingIcon.png" style="display:none;" />
    <form method="POST" action="js.php" onsubmit="javascript:loadLoader()">
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In first, let's talk about what's going on when you submit a form.
Browser calls `onsubmit` method and after starts to prepare `POST` request and sends it to the server. After `POST` request browser get a new html page, browser unload old page and load new one.

You wouldn't see the `loadingImage` if whole process is too fast. But if server handles `POST` request slowly, you will see loading image on old page before browser will render new page.

You can try to add `console.log` and turn on a console flag to prevent cleaning for logs and you will see `'show loader'`, but you will not see image, because browser has been loading new page and handling it.

```
function loadLoader(){
    console.log('show loader');
    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display = 'block';
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call function `onClick` attribute of Button and by Id of Button.

option 1: With `OnClick` attribute

```
<html>
<body>    
  <img id="loadingImage" src="assets/images/loadingIcon.png" style="display:none;"/>
  <form method="POST" action="js.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="loadLoader()"/>   
  </form>

<script  type="text/javascript">
function loadLoader(){
    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display = 'block';
    return true;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Option 2: Button Click event by Id

```
<html>
<body>    
  <img id="loadingImage" src="assets/images/loadingIcon.png" style="display:none;"/>
  <form method="POST" action="js.php">
    <input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Go"/>   
  </form>

<script  type="text/javascript">
$("#btnsubmit").click(function() {
    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display = 'block';
    return true;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Option 3: By Form Submit Method

```
<html>
<body>    
  <img id="loadingImage" src="assets/images/loadingIcon.png" style="display:none;"/>
  <form method="POST" action="js.php">
    <input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Go"/>   
  </form>

<script  type="text/javascript">
$('form').submit(function() {
    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display = 'block';
    return true;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```